# Checking which raidoButton in a ButtonGroup is selected?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created both my 2 radioButtons and my ButtonGroup in Swing. They are "radioAscending", "radioDescending", and "buttonGroupAscDsc" respectively. When "radioAscending" is selected, an array will be sorted in ascending order, and vice versa. However, when I try to check if one of the two is selected:

```
if (radioAscending.isSelected()) {
    Arrays.sort(alphaArray, (String[] s1, String[] s2) -> s1[0].compareToIgnoreCase(s2[0]));
    alphaModel = new DefaultTableModel (alphaArray, columns);
}
```

the top line gives the error:

```
non-static variable radioAscending cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: error seems to be clear

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided doesn't show much, however from the error it looks like you are calling a variable `radioAscending` which is not static (not marked with keyword `static`) from a method which is marked as static `static`, which is not allowed.